# log4j - show logs both in file and console

Tags: java, logging, log4j, appender

I have two appenders, one for file and another for console.
I want Eclipse console to show both file and console logs, but in the same time file to show only its own logs.
How do I do that?

Here is conf.

```
<appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
 <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
 <param name="Append" value="true"/>
 <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
 <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/file.log"/>
 <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p %m%n"/>
 </layout>
```

```
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
  <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
  <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
  <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
     <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/>
  </layout>
```

Also, file log is showing only logs from specific package.

```
<category name="com.project.example" additivity="false">
   <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
   <priority value="INFO"/>
</category>
```

And root:

```
<root>
  <priority value="${jboss.server.log.threshold}"/>
  <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
  <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure your `appender` in `logger` tag as below.

```xml
<logger name="com.project.example">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
</logger>
<root>
    <level value="debug" />
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
</root>
```